How can DAPR declarative pubsub subscriptions be made in order to pass a custom cloud event attribute?
I have an integration with an external system that produces cloud events into a pub sub (Kafka). These cloud events include the tenant information in custom cloud event properties.
I want to perform a declarative subscription but I cannot find any example on how to indicate how to pass these information into the request.
Are they all passed as http headers?
https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/pubsub/subscription-methods/#declarative-subscriptions
In programatic susbcriptions I cannot find any example either.
